# No background image being displayed on Galaxy Nexus (ONLY)?

Tags: android, xml, user-interface, background, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

Very peculiar problem here, Simply the background image asset will display fine on ALL phones except the Galaxy Nexus (or i have found so far)

Find below the gallery of the app in multiple different phones, but note in image number SIX the nexus does not have the background?

I have set support for all density's and large + XL screen sizes, i shall post the XML of one layout, however its spans across ALL layouts, whether it has any controls/linear Layouts or whatever else.

Images: http://goo.gl/59c8C

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent" android:background="@drawable/app_bg">

     <ScrollView
         android:id="@+id/scrollView12"
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" android:fillViewport="true">

         <RelativeLayout
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="match_parent" >

                 <LinearLayout
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">


             <com.quickcontact.CustomTextView
                 android:id="@+id/CustomTextView01"
                 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                 android:gravity="center"
                 android:text="Tap the buttons below to create your contact profiles. You will be able to assign contact details to each of your profiles and share them with others."
                 android:textColor="#3f3f3f"
                 android:textSize="15sp" android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" android:layout_marginRight="10dp" android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"/>

             <com.quickcontact.CustomTextView
                 android:id="@+id/receiveHeadertxt"
                 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                 android:gravity="center"
                 android:text="-- Create Profile --"
                 android:textColor="#3f3f3f"
                 android:textSize="15sp" android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"/>

             <com.quickcontact.CustomButton
                 android:id="@+id/butPersonal"
                 android:layout_width="match_parent"
                 android:layout_height="78dp"
                 android:background="@drawable/standard_button"
                 android:padding="1dp"
                 android:text="Personal"
                 android:textColor="#3f3f3f"
                 android:textSize="16sp" />

             <com.quickcontact.CustomButton
                 android:id="@+id/butSocial"
                 android:layout_width="match_parent"
                 android:layout_height="78dp"
                 android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                 android:background="@drawable/standard_button"
                 android:padding="1dp"
                 android:text="Social"
                 android:textColor="#3f3f3f"
                 android:textSize="16sp" />

             <com.quickcontact.CustomButton
                 android:id="@+id/butBusiness"
                 android:layout_width="match_parent"
                 android:layout_height="78dp"
                 android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                 android:background="@drawable/standard_button"
                 android:padding="1dp"
                 android:text="Business"
                 android:textColor="#3f3f3f"
                 android:textSize="16sp" android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"/>

             <com.quickcontact.CustomButton
                 android:id="@+id/butNext"
                 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                 android:layout_height="58dp"
                 android:background="@drawable/blue_button"
                 android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
                 android:paddingBottom="1dp"
                 android:text="NEXT"
                 android:textColor="#3f3f3f"
                 android:textSize="16sp" />

         </LinearLayout>

         </RelativeLayout>

     </ScrollView>

 </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Galaxy Nexus is an xhdpi device. Is the background image located in the `/res/drawable-xhdpi/` directory?

Another option, if your background just a gradient then you could write a gradient script in xml and just place it in your `/res/layout/app_bg.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<item>
    <shape>
        <gradient
            android:startColor="@color/green2"
            android:endColor="@color/green1"
            android:gradientRadius="555"
            android:type="radial" />
    </shape>
</item>
</selector>
```

Then reference your background as `android:background="@layout/app_bg"`

My preference is to create one single layout style xml for consistent styles throughout the app and then just include them in all other xml layouts.

Comment: I know this is a really old question. Anyway, the problem is still here... This is a great workaround. The solution you provide works perfectly. In my case, I have a complex gradient (multi-directionnal, etc...) so it would be much easier for me to use a picture... So, I don't know where the problem come form. My resources are in xhdpi folder... Do you have some other clues ?

Comment: I am also facing same issue on Samsung Nexus and for some of my RelativeLayouts I am not able to see background images, my background image is in drawable folder. i tried with xml shape as given in the answer it works with shape but not with the image as background, please let me know if someone has found fix for it.